# How to covert JSON data in separate arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript

My `JSON` data has following format :

```
[{"Name":"A","Id":"1"},{"Name":"B","Id":"2"},{"Name":"C","Id":"3"}]
```

How covert this into two separate arrays as `Name[]` and `Id[]` using `JavaScript` ?
I need the data in the following manner:

```
Name[0] should be : "A"
Name[1] should be : "B" and so on ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data = [{"Name":"A","Id":"1"},{"Name":"B","Id":"2"},{"Name":"C","Id":"3"}];

var result = {};
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    for (var key in data[i]) {
        var item = data[i][key];
        if (key in result)
            result[key].push(item);
        else
            result[key] = [item];
    }
}

result.Name // ["A","B","C"]
result.Id // ["1","2","3"]
```

Comment: +1. The one who downvoted this probably doesn't understand generic solutions =p

Answer (score 1):

this should work, jsonArray is your JSON

```
var name = [], ids = [];
jsonArray.forEach(function(item){
  name.push(item.Name);
  ids.push(item.Id);
}
```

Comment: Its not working for me.. The JSON data which I want to covert to arrays is  actually in the xmlHttp.responseText (since m getting it from a web service)..

Comment: You wrote that your jsonData is in this format. so whats the format of your jsonData? if it is wrapped in xhr.resposneText you need to parse it as JSON or provide the code.

Comment: this is my script code : var Url = "some url"; var xmlHttp = null; xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); xmlHttp.open( "GET", Url, false ); xmlHttp.send( null ); alert(xmlHttp.responseText);  the alert shows the mentioned data

Comment: Then you need to parse `xmlHttp.responseText` which is delivered as String. Within alert this is a String and not an array.

Comment: How do I do that? :( I am pretty new to java script.

Comment: Usually all common JS frameworks (like jQuery) support this or you try `var jsonArray = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use miso project if you are handling a lot of data with different source.

```
var ds = new Miso.Dataset({
  data: [ 
    { one : 1, two : 4, three : 7 },
    { one : 2, two : 5, three : 8 }
  ]
}).fetch({
  success: function() {
    log( this.column('one').data );
  }
});
```

http://misoproject.com/dataset/api.html#misodataset_i_fetch